# Error: Failed to parse regular expression "": pattern too large - compile failed

Tags: google-bigquery, re2

I find the following phenomena:

I have a BQ query with 100s of fields extracted using REGEXP_EXTRACT function.

I added a new expression and got the following Error: Failed to parse regular expression "": pattern too large - compile failed.

When querying this expression alone, everything runs fine, in a larger query, i get the error.

This is a replica of the problem base on the github sample data and a simple regex:

```
    SELECT repository.description,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(repository.description,r'(?:\w){0}(\w)') as Pos1,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(repository.description,r'(?:\w){1}(\w)') as Pos2,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(repository.description,r'(?:\w){2}(\w)') as Pos3,
.
. here it goes on and on in the same pattern
.
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(repository.description,r'(?:\w){198}(\w)') as Pos199,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(repository.description,r'(?:\w){199}(\w)') as Pos200,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(repository.description,r'(?:\w){200}(\w)') as Pos201,
    FROM [publicdata:samples.github_nested] LIMIT 1000
```

It returns:

```
Failed to parse regular expression "(?:\w){162}(\w)": pattern too large - compile failed
```

but when running:

```
SELECT repository.description,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(repository.description,r'(?:\w){162}(\w)') as Pos163,
FROM [publicdata:samples.github_nested] LIMIT 1000
```

Everything runs OK...

Is there a limit to # of REGEXP_EXTRACTs, or their combined complexity, that can be used in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

I'll look into the issue. As a workaround, it looks like what you're trying to do is to split out the field into separate fields per character position... so turn "abc" into {pos1: "a", pos2: "b", pos3: "c"}. Is that correct? If so, you might want to try the LEFT() and RIGHT() functions. As in

```
LEFT(1, reponsitory.description) as pos1,
RIGHT(1, LEFT(2, reponsitory.description)) as pos2,
RIGHT(1, LEFT(3, reponsitory.description)) as pos3.
```

This should use fewer resources than compiling 200 regular expressions (although it is still not likely to be fast).

Comment: Thanks, the my query is just a sample that reproduces the issue. My real query  just contains many regex expressions.